# scrollIntoView is not working as expected in safari browser

Tags: javascript, scroll, safari

I have this scrollable div and inside i have an SVG with points that has id's given. i want to align the selected point to the centre of the div and i have this solution

```
document.getElementById("myID").scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth', 
    block: 'nearest', 
    inline: 'center' 
 })
```

this works fine in chrome but in safari it's not working, what is the best solution ?

Comment: In what way is it specifically, "not working"?

Comment: in chrome its scrolling the element to center if possible, but in safari its scrolls to wrong element or position @jmargolisvt

Comment: Hard to diagnose with the information given. Can you provide enough code to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not supported in Safari.  Specifically, `scrollIntoViewOptions` is not supported, so you'll need to find a polyfill for this or employ another method entirely.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: this library solved the issue, https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamless-scroll-polyfill

Comment: The library which was proposed @RanjithM  work like a charm! Thanks. Thanks.