# element scrollIntoView does not work in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

This function is used get element into view

```
if (elmement) {
      const rect = elmement.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (rect.top < 0 ) {
        elmement.scrollIntoView(true );
      } else if (rect.bottom > window.innerHeight) {
        elmement.scrollIntoView(rect.top <= 0);
        }
      }
```

does not work in safari 14 but works in chrome any solution ??

as per doc safari 14 supports boolean
[enter link description here](https://caniuse.com/scrollintoview)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrollIntoView is not working as expected in safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552682/scrollintoview-is-not-working-as-expected-in-safari-browser)

Comment: @NeutralMe nope in safari scrollIntoView [link](https://caniuse.com/scrollintoview) boolean supports and i am sending boolean

Comment: I think it is **not supported** if you look closely you will see it say **Partial support**. which means not suppoted completely. Also if you go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). It will say it is **not supported** for Safari on iOS.